# Installed Windows Vista on a system with Ubuntu, Ubuntu not visible at boot time

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, boot

Hello my system had Windows Server and Ubuntu running on it, recently I uninstalled Windows Server and installed Windows Vista. I used GParted to remove the Windows server instance. Now during boot time, I do not see the option to select either Vista or Ubuntu option. It directly boots into Vista. What do I do now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EasyBCD to modify your boot record to configure with Ubuntu as well.

http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1

Comment: GRUB (The bootloader that boots Ubuntu) is completely removed by the Windows installation...

Answer (score 2):

Your bootloader (GRUB) has been erased by the Vista install. Do the following: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 0):

A brief addendum for future readers who stumble on this topic and want dual boot systems.
If you have the opportunity install windows first.  In my experience (though only about 20 dual boot setups), Ubuntu sees and plays well with Windows if it finds it already on the disk. I have not found the reverse to be true.
If you are putting Ubuntu on as a secondary system via WUBI (Windows will boot by default) then just do it by loading the Ubuntu CD with Windows running.
If you are re-partitioning and doing a normal Ubuntu install (Ubuntu will boot by default), then resize the Windows partition from the Live-CD, reboot Windows which will run chkdsk and mark the partition as clean, then do a full Ubuntu install.